# c++: segmentation fault, core dumped

Tags: c++

I have been experimenting with binary trees. I am trying to build an expression tree with the below c++ code. but, i keep getting `segmentation fault(core dumped)` during runtime

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct tree{
   char data;
   tree *left=NULL;
   tree *right=NULL;
   tree *parent=NULL;
};   
tree* newNode(char d)
{
   struct tree* node = new tree;
   //struct tree* nodep = &node;
   node->data = d;
   return node;
}

tree* parseTree(string expression)
{
   vector<char> tokens;
   for(int i = 0; i<expression.size(); i++)
      tokens.push_back(expression[i]);
   struct tree* currentNode = newNode(' ');
   struct tree* prevNode = new tree;
   for(int i = 0; i<tokens.size(); i++)
   {
      if(tokens[i]=='(')
      {
         currentNode->left = newNode(' ');
         prevNode = currentNode;
         currentNode = currentNode->left;
         currentNode->parent = prevNode;
      } 
      else if(tokens[i]=='+'||tokens[i]=='-'||tokens[i]=='*'||tokens[i]=='/')
      {
         currentNode->data = tokens[i];
         prevNode = currentNode;
         currentNode = currentNode->right;
         currentNode->parent = prevNode;
      }
      else if(isdigit(tokens[i]))
      {
         currentNode->data = tokens[i];
         prevNode = currentNode;
         currentNode = currentNode->parent;
      }
      else if(tokens[i]==')')
      {
         prevNode = currentNode;
         currentNode = currentNode->parent;
      }
   }
   return currentNode;
}
int main()
{
   string expression = "(3+(4*5))";
   struct tree* root = parseTree(expression);
   return 0;
}
```

I tried different things but i couldn't get rid of this error

what am i missing?
why do i get this error?
how to rectify this?

Comment: Probably the best option is to use a debugger such as gdb and see the bakctrace.

Comment: You are leaking 2 instances of `tree`: in parseTree `struct tree* prevNode = new tree;` which is never used before being set to a new value. in main: `struct tree* root = new tree;`

Comment: Sidenote: Include `<cctype>` instead of `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: `valgrind` says: `==1706288== Invalid write of size 8
==1706288==    at 0x401357: parseTree(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) (in /home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/seg2-clang)
==1706288==    by 0x401475: main (in /home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/seg2-clang)
==1706288==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
`

Comment: Why do you set `root` equal to a `new tree` only to then replace it with `parseTree(expression)`? What's the point of dynamically allocating a new tree only to, one line later, lose the pointer to it and leak it? (You do the same thing with `prevNode`.)

Comment: Please refrain from posting duplicate (or in this case triplicate) questions.

Comment: @bitmask apologies senor

Comment: This code looks like a weird blend of C code with a little bit of C++ seasoning.

Answer (score 1):

```
  else if(tokens[i]=='+'||tokens[i]=='-'||tokens[i]=='*'||tokens[i]=='/')
  {
     currentNode->data = tokens[i];
     prevNode = currentNode;
     currentNode = currentNode->right;
     currentNode->parent = prevNode;
  }
```

No code ever sets any `right` to anything other than `NULL`. So in the last line, `currentNode` is `NULL` and you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Also, take a look here:

```
struct tree* prevNode = new tree;
```

This value is never used and when the value is changed, the `tree` you allocated here is leaked.

Answer (score 1):

This part uses `->right`, which was never set:

```
  else if(tokens[i]=='+'||tokens[i]=='-'||tokens[i]=='*'||tokens[i]=='/')
  {
     currentNode->data = tokens[i];
     prevNode = currentNode;
     currentNode = currentNode->right;
     currentNode->parent = prevNode; // SEGFAULT
  }
```

So you are trying to write to address `0 + some offset`, which you are not allowed to.